ESEF - same fact but different values lead to duplicated_facts error
I am generating an ESEF report from my application.
Now I have a text e.g.: "this year we made a revenue of ~124 mio €"
And the value 123 mio € in a table.
Both values are connected to the same data value in the database which has the exact value of 123569815,46 €
In the report they are just displayed differently (123 - 124)
Now I have two different resulting nonFraction elements:
<ix:nonFraction contextRef="D-01012024-31122024" decimals="-6" format="ixt4:num-comma-decimal" id="esef-9696_2024_74477_1" name="ifrs-full:Revenue" scale="6" unitRef="euro">124,0</ix:nonFraction>

<ix:nonFraction contextRef="D-01012024-31122024" decimals="-6" format="ixt4:num-comma-decimal" id="esef-9696_2024_74375_1" name="ifrs-full:Revenue" scale="6" unitRef="euro">123</ix:nonFraction>

When I validate them via Arelle I get an error:

[message:tech_duplicated_facts1] Duplicated facts with different values have been reported for: ix:nonFraction, value:123000000 != 124000000 please review selected entries.

Is there a designated attribute or something similar for such cases?

The new Calculations 1.1 specification, currently rolled out and recommended by the ESEF reporting manual as of 2024, clarifies the precision semantics for values used in calculations (which revenues typically are, as part of the income statement roll-up structure).
123 with a scale of 6 and with -6 decimals is consistent with an exact value in the interval [122500000, 123500000].
124 with a scale of 6 and with -6 decimals is consistent with an exact value in the interval [123500000, 124500000].
An exact value of 123569815,46 is thus consistent with the 124 tag, but not with the 123 tag.
One could consider setting decimals to -7, however, Calculations 1.1 would then disallow the 3 in 123 as digits in excess of the precision.
The recommended course of action would be to check if the displayed value 123 in the table is correctly computed. If this has to do with the consistency between roundings and subtotals, the insights and advice given in Calculations 1.1 could help, in particular: calculations do not need to match exactly, but only require that the intervals of allowed exact values overlap.
